# How to restrict a website running under GCP App Engine to be accessible from Corporate network?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

How to restrict a website running under App Engine to be accessible from enterprise corporate network only?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [App Engine Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls).

In this case, you have to [add a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) for the mentioned network. Once you have created that, you can edit the default rule to deny access from other IP's.

If your website communicates with other apps or services in App Engine, [you have to consider adding the following rules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls#allowing_requests_from_your_services).

Answer (score 1):

Google offers the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy for AppEngine and it's free.  The only gotcha is that your users will need to fall into one of these categories:

1. Google account
2. Service account
3. Google group
4. G Suite domain
5. Cloud Identity domain

The documentation is here: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/